# Code to use fiddler functionality

Tags: fiddler

I want to use my code as if working like fiddler (a virtual fiddler through Code)using C # code..?
Is it possible...?
If yes, can anyone suggest code for it or atleast methods...!
Thank you,
Praveen

Answer (score 2):

You should go look at http://www.fiddler2.com/core. FiddlerCore is a class library you can use inside your C# project.